# How to Evaluate Expected Value powered 4 of a Wiener Process?

Tags: wienerprocess, expected-value

Since $X(t_j) - X(t_{j-1})$ is Normally distributed with mean zero and variance $t/n$ we have

$$ \operatorname{E} [(X(t_j) - X(t_{j-1}))^2 ] = \frac{t}{n} \tag{1}$$
and
$$ \operatorname{E} [(X(t_j) - X(t_{j-1}))^4 ] = \frac{3t^2}{n} \tag{2}$$

---

I can't seem to understand how the second result (2) is obtained. This is from Quantitative Finance by Paul Wilmott.

Answer (score 1):

You state $X(t_j) - X(t_{j-1}) \backsim \mathcal{N}(0, \frac{t}{n})$. Thus:
\begin{equation}
X(t_j) - X(t_{j-1}) = \sqrt{\frac{t}{n}} Z ,
\end{equation}
where $Z \backsim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$. Note that:
\begin{align}
& \mathbb{E} \sqrt{\frac{t}{n}} Z = 0 \\
& \mathbb{E} \left( \sqrt{\frac{t}{n}} Z \right)^2 = \frac{t}{n} \mathbb{E} Z^2 = \frac{t}{n} \\
& \mathbb{E} \left( \sqrt{\frac{t}{n}} Z \right)^3 = \left( \frac{t}{n} \right)^{\frac{3}{2}} \mathbb{E} Z^3 = 0 \\
& \mathbb{E} \left( \sqrt{\frac{t}{n}} Z \right)^4 = \left( \frac{t}{n} \right)^2 \mathbb{E} Z^4 = \frac{3 t^2}{n^2}
\end{align}
The third line follows since $\mathbb{E} Z^3 = 0$ and the fourth line follows since $\mathbb{E} Z^4 = 3$.

This result for the fourth moment of the Standard Normal is in many textbooks, but a proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1917647/proving-ex4-3%CF%834) on Mathematics StackExchange.